# aSlot.click do |button, left, top| # Help?

Tags: button, click, shoes

In what format is 'button' stored?

```
if button == 1
```

doesn't work for testing left mouse button click.

Comment: You should probably provide more details. It's hard to answer a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your handler try calling debug(button)

But click do |button, left, top| ... end seems to be giving me 1 = left mouse button, 2 = middle mouse, 3 = right mouse button, so maybe you're doing something else wrong ;)